# How to select the first empty cell in a column on a different sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty new to using VBA and I need to select the first empty cell in column B on the first sheet (not the active sheet). Whenever I try to activate the code I get an error on:

```
Cell.Select
```

What would I need to change in order to resolve this issue? Below is the code I am trying to use:

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("sheet1")
    For Each Cell In ws.Columns(2).Cells
        If IsEmpty(Cell) = True Then Cell.Select: Exit For
    Next Cell
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Aside from the question, you very rarely want to `Select` or `Activate` anything. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Sheets can be renamed and reordered.  The first (leftmost) sheet will be `Worksheets(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can immediately select the next free cell without looping:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Cells(1, "B").End(xlDown).Offset(RowOffset:=1).Select
```

Note that this will select the *next* free cell in column B (B4 in the example below), while the following code will select the free cell *after* the last used cell in column B (B14 in the example below):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1).Select
```

But note that using `.Select` is a bad practice: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Only use `.Select` if you want  the user to see that this cell is selected now.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I receive "error 1004" When I try to run the following code:

````Sub CellSelect()
    
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Cells(1, "B").End(xlDown).Offset(RowOffset:=1).Select
    
End Sub
````

Comment: The error is on the 

```ws.Cells(1, "B").End(xlDown).Offset(RowOffset:=1).Select
```
line

Comment: @ArmanKhachaturyan Because you have no data in column B below B1